# Cygwin ar requires elevation

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, unix-ar

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) x64, Cygwin 2.9.0 x64 on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 (I'm at work).

When trying to compile a simple hello-world project all works fine, so having verified that the Cygwin toolchain is working, I deleted the sample project and imported a whole bunch of projects that I pulled from SVN and have been verified to work on co-worker's computer.

When I build a project, I get:

```
ar -r  "libAAA.a"  ./A.o ./B.o ./C.o ./D.o ./E.o ./F.o
ar: creating libAAA.a
ar: libAAA.a: Permission denied
make: *** [makefile:46: libAAA.a] Error 1
```

(similar messages for each dependency project, i.e. object files generated by the compiler, but the `ar` tool fails)

All the filenames have been modified (sorry, NDA...), but they are all present in the current folder (`Debug`)

I was thinking the folder permissions were at fault, but I noticed that the object files are created in the same location with no problem. The `.a` file is created, with only a header in it (`!<arch>\n`), so folder write permissions are not an issue.

When I ran the same command `ar -r  "libAAA.a"  ./A.o ./B.o ./C.o ./D.o ./E.o ./F.o` from an elevated command line (cmd->Run as Administrator), all worked fine.

So my understanding is that the `ar` tool refers to something that is inaccessible to a regular user, so elevation is required.

I am able to run something as admin, but at work that's a separate user, then any files created by that user are not accessible by me, I have to enter a 30+ character password every time, and for a number of other reasons including security I'd rather not.

Has anyone had a similar issue? Is there a workaround? How could I check what `ar` is doing behind the scenes (other than decompiling into assembly please).

Comment: check ACL permission on the directory and on the file created when admin. To verify what ar is doing you can use `strace`

Comment: Thanks. The permissions were ok, there is a small possibility that something was messed up within Eclipse. Although I got the latest version of Eclipse CDT , when I went to `Help->Install New Software`, only one of the two "CDT Main Features" was installed. In the end, I'm not sure what it was, but I got a second hard drive installed and moved the project folders there, also moved the Cygwin and Eclipse there too (fresh install of both) and followed the "CDT Main Features" installation, now everything works.

Comment: Seems like the real problem with `ar` is the long paths (although, nowhere near 255 chars). My coworker was setting up the environment and no matter what we tried, he kept getting the `Permission denied` error, until we moved the project folder to something like `C:\Soft\lib_project` now all works. Still doesn't make sense why it worked fine under admin though.